# How to log successful login attempts to a database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to log database name when auditing logins in SQL Server (2005 and above)?

I basically want to log the username and the database name the user successfully connected to.

I have tried profiler, databasename column is blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to use a [Logon Trigger](http://sqlandme.com/2011/07/13/sql-server-login-auditing-using-logon-triggers/)

Just make sure your trigger captures `SYSTEM_USER` and `ORIGINAL_DB_NAME()` (this is only available in SQL 2008 +).

Just be careful with logon triggers. If you mess them up you can prevent any logins, because when they fail they cause the login to fail and then you have to use a workaround to get into the system and drop the trigger so you can fix it.

Don't let that hinder you though, just know you need to test them out thoroughly before you go throwing them onto a production server.

Comment: DAC does not fire logon trigger, so can use that in case of problems.

Comment: Thanks Levi. I created a trigger. Quick and easy. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you [configured login auditing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175850%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)?

Comment: Yes. But that doesnt log datbasename.

Comment: Hmmm... How are you reading the audit log? [fn_get_audit_file()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280765.aspx) may be helpful. `database_name` is listed as part of the data that is returned.

Comment: I was just using the default log viewer. However I tried using the fn_get_audit_file() function, but it returned no rows for the file. (it gets logged to the error file. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769099/where-are-sql-server-connection-attempts-logged))